# How to use QAbstractTableModel.submit\revert methods?

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyside

I'm trying to do a record-based in-grid editing with my own `QAbstractTableModel`-descendant class and a `QTableView`. When the editing is finished, the model recieves a signal to it's `submit()` or `revert()` slots. But there are no parameters, so the model does not know which record it needs to submit to (refresh from) a datastore. I've tried to setup my own change-tracking by catching `model.setData()/removeRows()/insertRows()` , but it's kind of a mess. Is there a right way to do it?

Comment: So which `QAbstractTableModel` descendant are you using? Some of them would already be tracking row changes, and the submit would get called when the current row finishes editing from the view. Or are you simply subclassing your own from `QAbstractTableModel`?

Comment: Yes, I'm simply subclassing my own from QAbstractTableModel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the docs on `QAbstractTableModel`:

> Subclassing
>
> When subclassing QAbstractTableModel, you must implement rowCount(),
>   columnCount(), and data(). Default implementations of the index() and
>   parent() functions are provided by QAbstractTableModel. Well behaved
>   models will also implement headerData().
>
> Editable models need to implement setData(), and implement flags() to
>   return a value containing Qt.ItemIsEditable.

So the fact that you are re-implementing `setData`, `removeRows`, and `insertRows` is appropriate. The other subclasses of this class also use their own internal caching to track what is being changed, so that it can commit it to the data source when needed. If your approach is a mess so far, then you probably just need to improve what you are doing, as the path is correct.

`setData` is where you can track what is being changed in an internal data structure. So for instance, if your model were a basic dictionary internally, and would submit to a web-based REST service, you would manage changes to the data in your internal dict. When `submit` is called, you would use that internal cache to make the necessary REST call to send out the data and sync it.

Comment: I understand that I can implement tracking myself, I just question the nesessity of doing that just for the sake of knowing which row user just finished editing. QTableView is allready perfectly aware of that as it's emitting signals to revert\submit slots, but isn't giving up that info. It looks like an oversight on the part of Qt developers. But oh well...

Comment: @AlexVhr: I don't think its an oversight. `submit` is not necessarily fired as a 1-to-1 with row editing. Your view may choose to call it when 10 rows are edited. In that case it has no correlation to a single row. Hence, with this class being an Abstract class, you need to track it yourself using `setData` as things are being actively edited. Because the model is separate from the view, it does not pretend to know how the view will be designed.

Comment: Model - yes, but the view does know, as it notifies the model about edits, but keeps it's mouth shut about details, thus forcing us to deduce what is going on in the view from inside the model.

Comment: What is stopping you from customizing the view to emit exactly what you want and connect it to the model to notify it?

Comment: Nothing. Everything can be implemented manually if need be, it's just that the presence of revert\submit slots and a phrase from the docs ("This function is typically used for row editing") gave me a hope that it's allready implemented.